# How to extract Bezeir curve information from pdf with pdf.js?

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

I want to extract the information of figures in PDF.
The figures are Bezeir curve, and I want to know the position, width, height of them.
How to extract that with pdf.js or other tools?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why getting the bezeir curve data from a PDF is useful for you. What do you do with that data afterwards? There may be an easier way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: My PDF is one of surveys, and it contains some choice format questions. Unfortunately, the answers are indicated with circle figure (it is created with curve).

Comment: You might want to consider the alternative of converting the PDF page to an image, and then passing that to some Computer Vision tool to locate the circles. I don't fully understand your problem domain but that might be easier.

Comment: So, I cannot extract the position of the curves from PDF file?

Comment: Of course you can, there should be many options out there for you. Though you only listed pdf.js and this is not a recommendations site. Depending on the API exposed by your chosen SDK library, you might have to do some additional maths to figure out where curves actually are, also you might have to worry about curves being clipped, and so on...